# People that don't do anything wrong

Tags: grammar

How to say in Korean:

**People that don't do anything wrong.**

How to negate relative clauses?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

They are negated in the same way as predicates in full sentences: “___ 하는 사람” becomes “___ 안 하는 사람” or “하지 않은 사람” for example.

For your example in particular, I might translate it as follows.
As an example of a full sentence:
“He didn’t do anything wrong”
“그는 잘못 없다”
So your clause could be
“잘못 없는 사람들”

Note that your example makes use of 없다 which is its own special negative form of 있다. So in this particular case we’re not using 안/않다, but it’s still following the same negation pattern as a full sentence.